# Building Final Web App from QGIS Web App Builder?

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite, boundless-web-app-builder

[image] I have used Web App Builder plugin for QGIS from Boundless to build a web application, but the application only shows in a browser when I click `Preview`.

The application created using `Create App` does not open up in browser. It says `Build final app using Boundless webSDK`.

I have read some documentation about the SDK, but I've got no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

When you preview the app in your browser check the URL (file://), copy it ,close the preview. Then paste the URL in your Windows File Explorer. Copy the whole directory where you want, rename the index_debug file to index.

Comment: The documentation says that the web app developed with preview is not suitable for development.......also says that wed need node.js and boundless web SDK to build final app. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I think it is a bug or something. But the preview app is identical to the final app.

Comment: The dialogue also says that the final product is not application but application file......we just have to figure out  how to use suite-sdk command to create application template

Comment: The suite-sdk command is the old SDK, this is not the same. The new Web SDK is only available to Boundless customers currently.

Answer (score 0):

in the file explorer type

```
%AppData%
```

Then go one directory up to local and browse to Temp. You should then find the `webappbuilder` folder and just copy the folder into whatever directory you want. I have emailed Boundless about this, and they have expressed that they are still working on the plugin. This is just a quickfix.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the qgis webappbuilder for a while and putting some of my own javascript development into the output.  It depends on which widgets and data you want to use; with my experience, data in WFS format are buggy with the webappbuilder (the source in the layer.source() argument includes other parameters instead of just the URL).  However, if you want to use the webappbuilder as just a viewing plaform as opposed to WFS-T editing, it does the job very nicely.

What @Balazs said is correct; get the output from the temporary folder and copy it locally.  However, chances are you will want to tweak it to your own needs after that as well.